# Android SSL usage: key input stream from UI thread to background thread

Tags: android, ssl, android-activity, thread-safety

I have a design question on android SSL socket usage. To be able to initialize a secure socket, I need to be able to access the key input stream from a background thread to initialize the session context. I use another key inputstream to initialize the HttpsURLConnection, but I do this in the UI thread (this may be unrelated.) I have several background threads operating on individual secure sockets and I want them to share a single SslContextFactory. See below. Is this a correct design? Is SSLContext thread-safe? If SSLContext is not thread-safe, I want to know how I can create a SSLContext for each thread without going back (i.e., waiting on the UI activity) to the UI thread to get a new key InputStream (stream on a raw resource) for each thread.

```
class SslSessionContextFactory
{
    SSLContext sslContext;

    public SslSessionContextFactory(SslInfo info) throws Exception
    {
        KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance(info.getKeyStoreType());

        // Obtain the input stream for the key <--- this is the code in question.
        store.load(info.newKeyStream(), info.getPassphrase().toCharArray());

        TrustManagerFactory factory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(
                                          TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        factory.init(store);

        // Initialize the SSL context.
        sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, getCertificates(), new SecureRandom());
    }

    public SSLSessionContext getSessionContext()
    {
        // Initialize the session context.
        SSLSessionContext sessionContext = sslContext.getServerSessionContext();
        sessionContext.setSessionCacheSize(SESSION_CACHE_SIZE);
        sessionContext.setSessionTimeout(SESSION_TIMEOUT);
        return sessionContext;
    }
}
```

Callers on the background threads would do:

```
SslSessionContextFactory cxtFactory = ...;
SocketFactory sktFactory = cxtFactory.getSessionContext().getSocketFactory();
... sktFactory.createSocket(host, port);
```